# Json Serialization body for multiple API requests

Tags: c#

I have an existing IIB API request with a Json body created using Json Serialization for creating a new API registration for an Automated Testing purpose.

```
    public class MqSubscriptionBody
    {
        public int SubscriberID { get; set; }
        public string Topic { get; set; }
        public string Protocol { get; set; }
        public string ResponseContentType { get; set; }
        public MQ MQ { get; set; }
    }

    public class MQ
    {
        public string DestinationQueue { get; set; }
    }
```

//Json Serialization

```
    public string MqInvalidSubscriptionBody()
    {
        MqSubscriptionBody jsonBody = new MqSubscriptionBody();                         
        MQ destQueue = new MQ();

        jsonBody.Protocol = "Test";
        jsonBody.ResponseContentType = "Test";
        jsonBody.SubscriberID = "Test";
        jsonBody.Topic = "Test";

        destQueue.DestinationQueue = "Test";
        jsonBody.MQ = destQueue;                                                        

        string jsonbodyString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonBody);
        return jsonbodyString;                                                          
    }
```

The request is success and it returns correct response. Now I need to add one more attribute into the Json body for another request (update existing registration).

Is there any way I can add the new attribute (subscription ID just above subscriber ID) just for the 2nd call(update registration). My expectation would be to call registration without 'SubscriptionID' and call update registration with 'SubscriptionID'.

I have added my new attribute into the existing class as below, Though its working for the 2nd request, Its failing the first request as the Subscription data also added into the first request.

```
public class MqSubscriptionBody
{
    public int SubscriptionID { get; set; }  //New Attribute
    public int SubscriberID { get; set; }
    public string Topic { get; set; }
    public string Protocol { get; set; }
    public string ResponseContentType { get; set; }
    public MQ MQ { get; set; }
}

public class MQ
{
    public string DestinationQueue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: _it doesn't work_ is not descriptive enough, please explain what you expect and what you actually receive. Do you populate `SubscriptionId` when you build the response?

Comment: Is the API you are calling one which you are developing?

Comment: RyanWilson, @JSteward, I have just updated the question slightly to understand more. Please refer the same

Answer (score 0):

You may like this. This approach I generally use while developing the API. The approach is to develop the separate `class` for `registration` and the `update registration`. As you have mentioned.

> My expectation would be to call registration without 'SubscriptionID' and call update registration with 'SubscriptionID'.

**- For Registration:**

```
public class MqSubscriptionBody
{
    public int SubscriberID { get; set; }
    public string Topic { get; set; }
    public string Protocol { get; set; }
    public string ResponseContentType { get; set; }
    public MQ MQ { get; set; }
}

public class MQ
{
    public string DestinationQueue { get; set; }
}
```

**- For Update Registration:**

```
public class MqSubscriptionBodyUpdate
{
    public int SubscriptionID { get; set; }
    public MqSubscriptionBody MqBody{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this way, However its coming up in the below order`{
 SubscriptionID: 0
 MqBody:{
   SubscriberID: xxx
   Topic: "TEST"
   Protocol: "TEST"
   ResponseContentType: "XML"
   MQ: {
    DestinationQueue: "TEST"
       }
  }
}` But I need it in the below order `{
 SubscriptionID: xxx
 SubscriberID: xxx
 Topic: "Test"
 Protocol: "Test"
 ResponseContentType: "Test"
 MQ: {
  DestinationQueue: "TEST"
 }
}` Any Idea?

Comment: Correct: The format will come in the the below order `{ SubscriptionID: 0 MqBody:{ SubscriberID: xxx Topic: "TEST" Protocol: "TEST" ResponseContentType: "XML" MQ: { DestinationQueue: "TEST" } } }`.

To support `{ SubscriptionID: xxx SubscriberID: xxx Topic: "Test" Protocol: "Test" ResponseContentType: "Test" MQ: { DestinationQueue: "TEST" } }`. 

You need to pass the `SubscriptionID  = 0` while registration in the OP. No need to follow my way of implementation.